# Created an Anaconda python3 environment but it still loads ipython 2.7.6

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I installed Anaconda on my Ubuntu linux 12.04LTS x64 box. It seems to work fine except for this. So I created a conda environment using the

```
conda create -n py33dev python=3 anaconda
```

When I try to run the ipython shell, I would expect to get the Ipython3 shell and notebook. However, it still loads the ipython 2.7.6 shell. I tried using the ipython3 command, but it will then load an ipython3 shell from my computer and not from Anaconda.

I tried to install ipython3 to the Anaconda environment using

```
pip install ipython3
```

and

```
conda install ipython3
```

However, when I do this I just get a message saying "No packages found matching: ipython3"

So I am not sure why Anaconda runs fine with python2 but not with python3--even though Continuum indicates it is python3 ready. Am I missing a step anywhere? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try running `ipython3`. The package is called `ipython`, but the script to start it is called `ipython3`. When we release IPython 2.0, it will install both `ipython` and `ipython3` (or `ipython2` on Python 2).

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks for the comment. Yeah, I tried that. So when I type ipython inside of Anaconda, the shell starts and it says Python 2.7.6 [Anaconda 1.8.0). But when I try ipython3, it just says "WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv . . ." The reason that I want Ipython3 to work in Anaconda is because I want the Ipython3 shell to have access to all of the libraries installed with Anaconda--otherwise I have to build and compile them myself, etc.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install ipython`? It should already be there because of anaconda, but maybe it isn't for some reason./

Comment: @ThomasK I just tried that and still no luck. It just says that ipython 1.1.0 py27_0 is already installed. Same response essentially when I try to do pip install ipython; it just says "Requirement already up-to-date." Seems like if I am in a python3 environment (as the Anaconda environment is configured for), that ipython should start ipython3. But that does not seem to be the case. Go figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to do "source activate py33dev"?

Comment: Hey @Peter Wang. So this worked in a very strange way. I have been using that conda-workon script to activate environments. So I found that when I do conda-workon py33dev, then the "ipython" command starts with ipython with python2.7.6 in a python3 environment. BUT, when I do the "source activate py33dev" then using the "ipython" command opens up the correct python3.3.2. Not sure why that would happen as the conda-workon script does not even address the python version, but your answer helped me to find that issue. Thanks for your help and for the help from Thomas K too.

Comment: Try adding `hash -r` to your workon script. Names that already in your `PATH` are hashed (cached), so if you just prepend a new path to your `PATH`, it won't find the right one until it is rehashed.